# android File array object is giving null

Tags: android

```
File file=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();
File[] ff=file.listFiles();
```

Here ff is giving me null instead of list of sdcard folders.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29.  **The result is null if this file is not a director**

Comment: try using  `File file= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "");`

Comment: Don't use `getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();` directly. See my answer

Comment: I hope you have provided required permission for it in manifest file. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

Use this mehod to get list of all files from external storage directory

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dirs = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath());

if(dirs.exists()) {
    File[] files = dirs.listFiles();
}
```

Comment: Why are you introducing 'dirs' where you have already 'sdcard'?